# VSCode with Multiple Nodes

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have two Node instances (0.10, 4.4.0) installed. How can I point VSCode to use one instead of the other?

**type**: In launch.json, what is type used for? There is no documentation for it. Can I replace "node" with an absolute path for my Node instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Type` is the type of configuration. Possible values are `node` and `mono`. You can't replace it with a path to your Node.js instance.

You can use the `runtimeExecutable` value in launch target configuration to point VS Code debugger to a specific runtime. It's a workspace relative or absolute path to the runtime executable to be used. Default is the runtime executable on the PATH.

But I strongly advise to use a version manager like [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to install and switch between desired Node.js versions. You can even configure it to use different versions per directory using [.nvmrc file](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#nvmrc) and [automate switching when directory is changed](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#deeper-shell-integration). This way VS Code will use runtime executable on the PATH and you'll be able to control the env variables using nvm.